# Promise pending, fulfilled not returning

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

Trying to display data from a json.
When I run my functions on the console, it shows:

*Promise {}* and *[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"*

But not actually returning anything.

```
getJobs = async () => {
try{
    response = await fetch("./data.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
} catch(error){
    console.log('Error getting data', error)
    }   
} 


renderJobs = async () => {
        const jobs = await getJobs();
        const view = `
            <div class='card-company'>
                ${jobs.map(companyName => `
                    <p>${companyName.company}</p>
                `).join('')}
            </div>
        `
        return view
}
```

I have all the *p* tags I need inside the property `[[PromiseResult]]` but nothing displaying in the document.

I have not been able to find anything like this, also if there's anything to improve in this snippet, I appreciate the feedback.

Thank you.

Comment: [Dracorex's answer'(https://stackoverflow.com/a/65067471/3617380) has got to the point, the problem lies in how you use `renderJobs()`. Please show us that part of your code, so people can provide further help

Answer (score 3):

Since these are `async` functions, you need to use `await` to get their final return value.

To log the HTML string, you can use `console.log(await renderJobs());`, and wherever you are running `renderJobs()` in your code, you will need to use `await` to get the HTML string as well.

Using `console.log(renderJobs());` will return the promise pending message you described because `async` functions return a promise, not the result of the promise. Using `await` returns the fulfilled value of the promise it is used on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an improper template to me. I'm not seeing a use for it in this case, anyways. Should be more like:

```
const M = tag=>document.createElement(tag);
const renderJobs = async () => {
  const jobs = await getJobs(), frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  let d;
  for(let o of jobs){
    d =  M('div'); d.className = 'card-company'; d.textContent = o.company;
    frag.appendChild(d);
  }
  // you could append frag here or return and append later
  return frag;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, are there any docs about this?

Comment: You mean [document.createDocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)? I only did that so you could have the collection all at once. Personally, I would just append to the DOM in the loop. You'll prefer DOM style JavaScript to attach Events, as well, and for overall performance *(vs .innerHTML)*. Oh... `for of` loops are well documented too.

Comment: I meant on what the right way of templating is. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: All functions would have to execute `$( /* in here */}` when using a template. There's tons of [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
getJobs = () =>
      new Promise((resolve) => {
        fetch("./data.json").then((data) => {
          resolve(data);
        });
      });

    renderJobs = async () => {
      const jobs = await getJobs();
      const view = (
        <div class="card-company">
          ${jobs.map((companyName) => <p>${companyName.company}</p>).join("")}
        </div>
      );

      return view;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I see an issue with how you are not handling an error. You need to return reject or throw an error. Otherwise, the promise will never be resolved

```
getJobs = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('./data.json')
    const data = await response.json()
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error getting data', error)
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
}

renderJobs = async () => {
  let jobs = []
  try {
    jobs = await getJobs()
  } catch(error) {
   console.log('Error getting data', error)

  }
  const view = `
            <div class='card-company'>
                ${jobs
                  .map(
                    (companyName) => `
                    <p>${companyName.company}</p>
                `
                  )
                  .join('')}
            </div>
        `
  return view
}
```